# Vue 2 + Vuex: Using state variables in computed property

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I have a Vuex instance with a couple variables:

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    start_date: moment().startOf('year').format("MM/DD/YYYY"),
    end_date: moment().format("MM/DD/YYYY")
  },
  mutations: {
    changeDate(state, date_obj) {
      state.start_date = date_obj.start_date
      state.end_date = date_obj.end_date
    }
  }
})
```

and I have my main Vue instance where the date properties are inherited from the `store`:

```
var employees = new Vue({
  el: '#employees',
  computed: {
    start_date() {
      return store.state.start_date
    },
    end_date() {
      return store.state.end_date
    },
    leads() {
      let filter_obj = {
        start_date: this.start_date,
        end_date: this.end_date
      }
      return this.fetch('potential_clients', filter_obj)
    }
  },
  methods: {
    fetch(model, args=null) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        console.log(resolve, reject)
        let url = "/" + model + ".json"
        console.log(url);
        $.ajax({
          url: url,
          data: args,
          success: ((res) => {
            console.log(res)
            this[model] = res;
            resolve(res)
          }),
          error: ((res) => {
            reject(res)
          }),
          complete: (() => {})
        })
      })
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.fetch('potential_clients')
  }
});
```

and I initially call `this.fetch('potential_clients')` without any extra arguments, however once the value for `start_date` and `end_date` are changed, I want to call something like `leads()` above.  However nothing changes when I change the values of `start_date` and `end_date`.

It might be worth noting that when I inspect in Chrome with the Vue plugin, and click on the root component, all of a sudden the changes show in the view?  very odd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any reference to a variable outside the scope of a Vue instance [will not be reactive](https://jsfiddle.net/xyfm7yo3/). This means the `store` object you are referencing is not reactive.

You need to refer to the Vue instance's internal reference to the store (`this.$store`), which *is* reactive:

```
start_date() {
  return this.$store.state.start_date
},
```

This is assuming you've passed the `store` in the config object of your root Vue instance (which in your example appears to be the `#employees` component):

```
var employees = new Vue({
  el: '#employees',
  store: store,
  ...
```